# Скрипт скачивания и запуска файла из Сети

Tags: vbscript, bat

Пример:

```
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe", 0 
oXMLHTTP.Send
Set oADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oADOStream.Mode = 3
oADOStream.Type = 1
oADOStream.Open
oADOStream.Write oXMLHTTP.responseBody
oADOStream.SaveToFile "C:\TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe", 2 
dim path, WshShell
path = "C:\"
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
WshShell.Run path & "TeamViewer_Setup_en.exe", ,true
```

Пример нашел в Сети, но он почему-то не работает.

Comment: Скорее всего, это не нужно. 272, 273 и 274 статья ждет.

Comment: Если бы это не нужно было, я бы не спрашивал.

Comment: "@Bazinga, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Для записи в корень диска С необходимы права администратора. Попробуйте запустить скрипт от имени администратора. 
Также, возможно, Ваш антивирус блокирует подобные действия, т.к. они характерны для вредоносных программ.
Если проблема не в этом, то, пожалуйста, более подробно опишите ее.